# Flutter Querying Search Bar

Tags: flutter, dart

This is how I fetch data from a Json file:

```
child: FutureBuilder(
            future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
                .loadString('files/myfile.json'),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              // Decode the JSON
              var newData = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
```

And this is the ListView where I place the info extracted:

```
return ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  String word = newData[index]['NAME'];
```

Now I would like to know how can I query these data in order to perform a basic search. The implementation of the searchBar I followed is:

```
filterSearchResults(String query) {
    List dummySearchList = [];
    dummySearchList.addAll(data);
    if (query.isNotEmpty) {
      List<String> dummyListData = [];
      dummySearchList.forEach((item) {
        if (item.contains(query)) {
          dummyListData.add(item);
        }
      });
      setState(() {
        newData=data;
      });
      return;
    } else {
      setState(() {
        return newData  //If anything found, return the whole list.
      });
    }
  }
```

but nothing seems to be working for me. Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: PLEASE HELP....

Answer (score 0):

Your listview builder is using newData, but your filtering logic is using the list data.

Inside your setState, after adding your filtered results, try:

```
newData = data;
```

Comment: I edited the code with your suggestion (see above) but in the debug terminal appears: Expected a value of type 'Iterable<dynamic>', but got one of type 'Null'